# Best practice for Electron latest version download URL

Tags: amazon-s3, electron, release

We're launching a new app built in [Electron](https://electronjs.org/) and was wondering if anybody has any tips on best practice for releases?

We use electron-builder, which packages and publishes each new release to our s3 bucket, but the files are named as such: appName-setup-1.0.3.exe

Is there an easy way to have a "latest" URL that always points to the latest app version? Right now it seems like we'll need to publish our new version, then create a copy as appName-setup.exe in our s3 bucket, with a nice URL always pointing to it...

Are there better methods?